# Can’t access config page of my ASUS after setting it as a media bridge

Tags: router, bridge

I set up my router (ASUS) to act as a media bridge, then I connected to the router using a Ethernet cable and Internet and everything works fine.

When I try to access the router using IP `192.168.1.1`, I see the login screen of my ISP, not the ASUS router. How can I find out which IP I can use to access my router? Keep in mind I am connected to the router via Ethernet.

Comment: Presumably you are also connected to the Internet, possibly through the new Asus router.  Can you share: Your current network settings (e.g. ipconfig /all, or ifconfig -a, or other appropriate command), and information on how the following devices are connected to each other (your computer, the Asus router, your ISP's hardware), including any devices or cables between them.

Comment: Yes, I am connected to the internet via the Asus router. The setup is as basic as that: PC -> ethernet conn -> Asus router -> wifi conn -> Internet wifi modem. Anything specific from ipconfig you want to see? It looks pretty standard.

Comment: ipconfig reporting of your computer's configured IP address, network, and gateway will tell me whether 192.168.1.1 is on that network and is that gateway, or if (perhaps), the ASUS router is offering a different network to your computer.  If the second, the gateway is almost certainly the IP address you will try to connect to to configure the ASUS router.  If you connect to one via WiFi and the other via ethernet cable, that will also be interesting to see.